# JS error in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code block, that works on every browser except IE 11. Im picking content from a json file based on a select drop down. I have read that IE 11 has no arrow function, how do I re-write this to work in IE 11?

```
$.getJSON('./AJAX/myfile.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    var filter = $('#select').val();
    var countryData = data.filter(el => el.selection === filter);
});
```

The issue is with the "(el => el.selection === filter);" -> "=>" arrow. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Sorry to offend you T.J. I couldn't find a question / answer that I could understand enough to get to work. I should have added "I have spent 2 hrs on this trying to get similar solutions to work, with no success".

Answer (score 0):

The *arrow function* here:

```
var countryData = data.filter(el => el.selection === filter);
```

can be re-written as:

```
var countryData = data.filter( function (el) {
    return el.selection === filter;
});
```

Comment: Thank you AndrewL, I was screwing up the return function. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

```
  var countryData = data.filter(function (el) { return el.selection === filter; });
```